# Using numdisplay, "An existing connection was forced to close by the remote host"

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've been learning to use python in astronomy and for that I'm following [this](http://home.fnal.gov/~neilsen/notebook/astroImagingDataReduction/astroImagingDataReduction.html#undefined) notes. In the very beginning the author does the following example:

```
>>> im = pyfits.getdata('http://das.sdss.org/www/cgi-bin/drC?RUN=3630&RERUN=40&CAMCOL=3&FIELD=83&FILTER=r')
>>> numdisplay.display(im,z1=1000,z2=1500)
```

I try to replicate it and I get:

```
>>> numdisplay.display(im,z1=1000,z2=1500)
Image displayed with Z1:  1000  Z2: 1500

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    numdisplay.display(im,z1=1000,z2=1500)
  File "C:\Mine\Python\lib\site-packages\numdisplay\__init__.py", line 446, in display
    _d.writeImage(bpix,_wcsinfo)
  File "C:\Mine\Python\lib\site-packages\numdisplay\displaydev.py", line 513, in writeImage
    self.writeData(_lx,_ydisp,_fpix[block,:])
  File "C:\Mine\Python\lib\site-packages\numdisplay\displaydev.py", line 379, in writeData
    self._writeHeader(opcode,self._MEMORY, -nbytes, x, y, frame, 0)
  File "C:\Mine\Python\lib\site-packages\numdisplay\displaydev.py", line 542, in _writeHeader
    self._write(a.tostring())
  File "C:\Mine\Python\lib\site-packages\numdisplay\displaydev.py", line 580, in _write
    nwritten = self._socket.send(s[-n:])
error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forced to close by the remote host
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I mean if I write `numdisplay.open()` everything is fine... I'm thinking that it might be my antivirus or something that doesn't let python to communicate with ds9... Can somebody help me?

**Edit:** Well it doesn't seem to be the antivirus. I stopped it and run the script and I got the same error.

Comment: Which antivirus do you have? I use Mcafee and I get this message sometimes, when playing with network operations.

Comment: @kevin I use avast. But it's weird since whatever it is causing the problem it allows python to retrieve a file from the internet but not connect with ds9.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting similar error messages, and I just tried adding a non-'None' argument to the bufname argument and it works (my image is about 4096.4096):

```
numdisplay.display(data,bufname='imt4096')
```